# SICK LMS1xx in Husky (Hydro)

Tags: husky, ros-hydro, sicklms

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, does anyone have any idea how to use SICK LMS100 laser scanner in Husky?

I have been trying to use the package provided in here - https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/LMS1xx - but could hardly make it. (error message I got : connection to device failed, changing of IP does not work)

Ubuntu 12.04.4 + Hydro.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191277/sick-lms1xx-in-husky-(hydro)/) by [DavidSuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/3574/davidsuh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidSuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/3574/davidsuh/) on 2014-08-26**:
Thanks Murilo. You were right, it was indeed IP problem. Someone else changed the IP in LMS while I was on my vacation last month. LMS now works nicely again. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm also using a Husky with LMS100 on 12.04 + Hydro. I forked the repo from clearpath and made very minor changes. Have you checked the IP configured on the LMS? Can you show your launch file?

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0